# Is there a way to get only the constants defined by my script?

Tags: ruby, constants

I want to get the constants **defined in my scripts**, suppose I have two files like this:

script_two.rb

```
TWO = 'this is 2'
```

script_one.rb

```
require_relative 'script_two'

ONE = 'this is 1'
# Check for constants
```

I want to know how to get the array of constants `[ONE, TWO]` (order doesn't matter).

I know that `Object.constants` gives an array of current constants but that includes lots of other constants like `TRUE`, `NIL`, etc.

I thought of keeping the result of that at the beginning and then call it again after requires so I can make the difference. But it's a bit ugly, isn't there another way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Ruby provide a constant\_added hook method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407908/does-ruby-provide-a-constant-added-hook-method)

Comment: I don't see it as a duplicate, but it's related. The main difference is that I don't want a hook or get all constants I just want **my** constants

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is tricky because not having a class your are putting your constants onto the main:Object when you run your script. So you need to be able to know what constants are defined before the script executes. Something like this would work:

```
#script_one.rb
obj_cons = Object.constants
require_relative 'script_two'

ONE = 'this is 1'
puts self.class.constants - obj_cons
```

That generates the array:  [TWO, ONE] -- which I believe is what you want.

```
$ ruby script_one.rb
TWO
ONE
```